# Android launching specific url with specific browser

Tags: android, uri, shortcut

Launching a specific browser by icon is done with a ACTION_MAIN.
Launching a specific url using default browser is done with a ACTION_VIEW.

What if you want to open a specific url in a specific browser?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you know the package name and the class name of the browser,you can use 
Intent.setClassName (String packageName, String className). looks like:

```
Intent i=new Intent(ACTION_VIEW, url);
i.setClassName("com.test.browser","BrowserActivity");
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can even call the specific browser via its package name.
Like this;

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.com"));
intent.setPackage("org.mozilla.firefox");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What if the desired browser (In above case Mozilla Firefox) is not installed on mobile?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it doesn't require knowing the Activity name.
@SAM I presume it would throw an ActivityNotFoundException. I would always recommend wrapping startActivity(intent) in a try catch, if the activity is not a part of your own app.

Answer (score -3):

I think this is a *setting*. You go to the Application Manager and go to your favorite Browser. Then at the Options it should show you to be your default.

*I am not an Android Developer by the way...*

Comment: i thank you for the answer but it is really not what i needed. (do not be offended by me marking it unusefull plz)